# No instance for (Show (Grafo1 Int)) arising from a use of ‘print’

Tags: estructuras-de-datos, haskell

soy nuevo en Haskell y mi problema trata de crear un grafo cuya altura es un número que yo le doy. Los nodos deben ir desde 1  a (2^h)-1

Por ejemplo.

treeFC 0 ->GVacio
treeFC 3 -> Arco 3 6 (Arco 3 7 (Nodo 6 (Nodo 7 (Arco 2 4 (Arco 2 5
(Nodo 4 (Nodo 5 (Arco 1 2 (Arco 1 3 (Nodo 2 (Nodo 3 (Nodo 1 GVacio))))))))))))

Mi código es el siguiente pero no puedo comprobar si funciona por el error del titulo del post. Cualquier ayuda es muy bienvenida.

```
module Main where
import Text.Show.Functions



data Grafo1 a = GVacio  |   Nodo a (Grafo1 a)  |   Arco a a (Grafo1 a) deriving Show
data Grafo2 a= G2 [a] [(a,a)]  deriving Show




-- union:: Grafo1 a -> Grafo2 a -> Grafo1 a 

main :: IO ()
main = return ()


treeFC :: Int -> Grafo1 Int 
treeFC 0 = GVacio
treeFC n = auxtreeFC 1 (2^n-1) (Nodo 1 GVacio)

auxtreeFC:: Int -> Int -> Grafo1 Int -> Grafo1 Int 
auxtreeFC x y g = if (2*x>y) then g
              else auxtreeFC  x (y-1) (Arco x y(Nodo y g))
```

Comment: Te falta el `deriving Show` en el tipo `Grafo1`

Comment: Aqui tienes un par de preguntas que creo son muy parecidas a la tuya: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504950/haskell-no-instance-for-show  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039159/haskell-no-instance-arising-from-a-use-of-print

Comment: @ChemaCortes Ya está solucionado, gracias